# Allow dashes and slashes in jQuery UI datepicker dateFormat

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to allow dashes and slashes in the dateFormat for jQuery UI DatePicker?

```
                $("#txtServiceDue").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "m-d-yy",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-20:+20"
                });
```

Maybe a regular expression that would allow both?

Comment: No. Date Format is how the widget writes the String but the User can type in an address if they choose with slashes. If they use the DatePicker it will always be shown as the Date Format is set.

Comment: You can change the date format at any point so that when the User selects a date, it uses slashes or dashes. So under what conditions do you want it to create a date with slashes versus dashes?

Comment: I have a requirement to allow both depending on the user's preference.

Comment: Where is the users preference set?

Comment: I meant depending on if they type in dashes or slashes.

Comment: That's what I am saying, if they type it in, it's their preference, but if they pop open the DatePicker, it will use Date Format when they click on a date. Since there is no way to know the users preference when they click on a date in the picker, there is no way to accomplish what you are suggesting.